# Cite references without square brackets using \setcitestyle

Tags: citing

I am trying to achieve Reference<sup>1</sup> but rather the `\setcitestyle{super}` results in Reference<sup>[1]</sup>. How to remove the square brackets?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how it can be done. It can be achieved by:

`\setcitestyle{sort&compress,open={},close={},numbers,super}`

Here, `open` and `close` with empty contents result in no brackets.